# WAMP Server: Apache PHPMyAdmin login screen not showing

Tags: windows, mysql, php, apache-2.4, phpmyadmin

I have recently setup a WAMP server (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) and i'm having trouble setting up PHPMyAdmin.

I didnt use XAMPP for any of this, i installed the services directly onto the server. 
I followed a video tutorial, in which i've been told to place the "phpmyadmin"
folder in the "htdocs" folder in the Apache directory. Here are two [screenshots(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TroqW.png) [of my directory(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNAZC.png).

Now when i open a browser and type in "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/",
it shows [some kind of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o52g.png), instead of the PHPMyAdmin Login page.

I did the exact same thing as the presenter in the tutorial i followed, yet it worked for him and not for me. 
So, what could i have done wrong?

Comment: The first screenshot is supposed to show the Apache directory.

Comment: Your Apache doesn't recognize PHP code as such. Therefore PHP won't be executed as code and instead  the raw source code rather than output is returned to you. _-_ In you apache configuration either the PHP module is not loaded  (`loadmodule ...`) , of the PHP module has not been configured to recognize the .php extension as PHP code (`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php`).